# How to get result of service method in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have this code :

```
PostApp.factory('loadPage', function ($http) {
return {
    loadOtherPage: function (page, status, permition, order, cultureId) {
        $http({
            url: '/Administrator/Post/PagedIndex',
            method: "POST",
            data: { page: page, status: status, permition: permition, order: order, cultureId: cultureId }
        }).success(function(data) {
            return  data;
        });

    }
};
```

});

```
PostApp.controller('PostController',
function ($scope, $http, loadPage) {
    $scope.status = 'Published';
    $scope.permition = 'Global';
    $scope.order = 'Asscending';
    $scope.cultureId = 1;
    $scope.ListOfItems = [];
    $scope.start = 2;
    $scope.skip = 10;

    $scope.loaddata = function () {
        $scope.ListOfItems = loadPage.loadOtherPage($scope.start, $scope.status, $scope.permition, $scope.order, $scope.cultureId);
    };
}
```

);

but dont set response of loadPage.loadOtherPage services in to $scope.ListOfItems varible.
the response is json in console of browser:

```
[{"PId":15,"Id":15,"Status":"انتشار","Permition":"سراسری","PublishedDateEn":"08/19/2013","Title":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","CultureId":1,"Username":"naser","CommentCount":0},{"PId":16,"Id":16,"Status":"انتشار","Permition":"سراسری","PublishedDateEn":"08/19/2013","Title":"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","CultureId":1,"Username":"naser","CommentCount":0},{"PId":17,"Id":17,"Status":"انتشار","Permition":"سراسری","PublishedDateEn":"08/21/2013","Title":"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz","CultureId":1,"Username":"naser","CommentCount":0}]
```

final $scope.ListOfItems is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED: Adding variables for extra clarity)

The `loadOtherPage` function does not return anything, that's why `$scope.ListOfItems` is empty. The proper way to do it is something like:

```
loadOtherPage: function (page, status, permition, order, cultureId) {
    var httpPromise =  $http({
        url: '/Administrator/Post/PagedIndex',
        method: "POST",
        data: { ... }
    });
    return httpPromise;
}
```

You essentially return the promise that `$http` returns, back to the caller. Your controller should become:

```
$scope.loaddata = function () {
    var loadPagePromise = loadPage.loadOtherPage( ... );
    loadPagePromise.success(function(data) {
        $scope.ListOfItems = data;
    });
};
```

Comment: very tanks.
but i return data in loadOtherPage function in service:

$http({url: '/Administrator/Post/PagedIndex',
      method: "POST",
      data: {...}
      }).success(function(data) {
            return  data;
      });
tanks.

Comment: `.success(function(data) { return data; })` simply registers an additional callback when the request succeeds. `return data;` is not the `return` statement of `loadOtherPage`. It's the `return` statement of the anonymous function you're giving into `success()`. Functional languages are a bitch, I know... :P